# Database for highway bus network

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm creating a database to store highway bus system. Basically, those buses are used by people who travel from one city to another. Depending on the departure city and the destination city, a person may have to take several buses to get to their desired destination. It's very similar to public transit system. The main difference is that the buses are run by several different companies and the database should allow an application to query the company information base on departure and destination city. Lets say user wants to travel from Rome to Vienna and it requires to take 3 buses to get there. By providing Rome as departure city and Vienna as a destination, my application would generate a query that returns a result like - Company1 (Name, Address, Contact Number), Company2(Name, Address, Contact Number), Company3 (Name, Address, Contact Number).

So Far, I have come up 4 tables :

```
Company - id,name, companyid, address, ph#

City - id,name

Bus - id,companyid,stopid

Stop - id, cityid
```

From there, I'm not sure what more tables to add so that my app can run queries for trips that requires to take more than one bus. I appreciate for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The tables and attributes you need are determined by the functional requirements you have. So, if you just need information about buses, the companies operating them, and the cities where they stop, your tables might contain enough information. If your requirements become more complex (or if there are requirements that you didn't explicitly state because you think they go without saying), some information might be lacking.

There is one formal flaw in your design. I assume that your `id` attributes shall contain a unique key for each record. If this is true, then you will have no more than one record for each bus, so only one stop can be associated with each bus. Also, you won't have more than one record for each stop, so only one city can be associated with each stop. So, even if each bus is considered to connect only two cities, you wouldn't be able to express the from-to-relationship.

There are two ways to fix this. If, when going from A via B to C, you don't care whether it's actually the same bus connecting them, it would suffice to define

```
Bus - id, companyid, originid, destinationid
```

and to omit the Stop table. That way, a traveler could get all available connections from Rome to Vienna, but for a chain containig Florence, wouldn't know whether to change buses there or just quietly to keep sitting.

If you want your Stop objects to describe an itinerary, they would have the structure

```
BusStop - id, busid, cityid, sequence
```

where the sequence attribute would count, from 0 or 1 upwards, the cities touched by this bus.

Another thing your model might be lacking is the notion of distances or travel times. There might be a connection from Rome via Stockholm to Vienna, but I doubt it would be very attractive. Airlines sometimes offer that kind of zig-zag route, but for buses it might be impractical. A similar observation holds for waiting times for the connecting bus. Going from Rome to Vienna via Florence, Venice, Klagenfurt, and Graz might be nice, but if it means waiting 2 days at each of these places for the next bus, using a bicycle might be a good alternative. Requirements like these might lead to drastically more complex data models.

Comment: Hi downvoter, what about giving some constructive criticism and tell us what needs improvement?